# Create Separate row for Spark DataFrame Array type

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have following spark dataframe schema

```
root
 |-- UserId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- VisitedCountry: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = false
 |    |    |-- Id: long (nullable = false)
```

i want to convert each VisitedCountry as seprate row within new dataframe

```
root
 |-- UserId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- CountryName: string (nullable = false)
 |-- CountryId: long (nullable = false)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expand array-of-structs into columns in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670923/expand-array-of-structs-into-columns-in-pyspark)

Comment: @user10938362 provided reference doesn't have any answers .

Comment: @Arash: The linked question itself (and the answer) actually have the solution you are after. First use `explode` and then put the values in the struct into their own separate columns. (and no, I'm not the one who downvoted if you were wondering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would probably want to use the explode function.

check out https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=explode

i'm not sure how it would work with structs.

Answer (score 1):

Explode & select, on Scala:

```
df.withColumn("exploded", explode($"VisitedCountry"))
  .select($"UserId",
    $"exploded.Name".alias("CountryName"),
    $"exploded.ID".alias("CountryId")
  )
```